# Best interface mock / fake with partial implementation

Tags: c#, mocking, integration-testing, partial

Is there a good tool under C#, to fake complex interfaces (service, repository and the like) with partial test implementations?

The mock framework I am currently using (RhinoMocks) is too slow and too hard to handle for this purpose.

Prerequisites:

- No significant performance penalty, compared to real implementations (bulk tests)
- Implementation with rudimentary logic and data (e.g.: dictionary instead of database table)
- No need to change the tests, when the interface changes.

Full implementation example:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    int PropertyA { get; set; }
    int PropertyB { get; set; }
    void DoSomethingWithX(int x);
    int GetValueOfY();
}

public class FakeImplementation : IMyInterface
{
    private int _valueOfYCalls = 0;

    public int PropertyA { get; set; }
    public int PropertyB { get; set; }
    public void DoSomethingWithX(int x)
    { }

    public int GetValueOfY()
    {
        return _valueOfYCalls++;
    }
}
```

The counter is just to simulate the rudimentary logic.

Problem is, if the interface gets a new method, like *SetSomeZ(int z)* , the test won't build/run anymore, without explicit change.

Is there a fake/mock framework, working with basic implementations, but adding members automatically, either via virtual/override, or wrapper?

Such as this:

```
[ImplementsInterface(nameof(IMyInterface))]
public class FakeImplementationBase
{
    private int _valueOfYCalls = 0;

    [ImplementsMember(nameof(IMyInterface.GetValueOfY))]
    public virtual int GetValueOfY()
    {
        return _valueOfYCalls++;
    }
}
```

The tool/framework should generate full implementation types at runtime, similar to mocks/stubs, but using the basic implementation, just adding the missing interface parts.

This is not supposed to be for real unit testing, but for more complex purposes. It's also legacy software with huge interfaces and classes, not much about "single responsibility".

Answer (score 0):

Moq is exactly what you want.

```
public interface IFoo {
    int MethodA(int a);
    void MethodB(long b);
    void MethodC(string c);
    ...
}

var MoqFoo = new Mock<IFoo>();
MoqFoo.Setup(m => m.MethodA(It.Is(a => a > 0)).Returns<int>(a => a + 1);
MoqFoo.Setup(m => m.MethodC(It.IsAny<string>()).Callback<string>(c => Debug.Write(c));
```

Note how we didn't do .Setup() for MethodB? When you declare it, all methods and properties get dummy methods/properties, .Setup() will specify your own custom ones.

So if your interface has 10 methods but you only want to test MethodD(), you only need to write code for that.

http://www.developerhandbook.com/unit-testing/writing-unit-tests-with-nunit-and-moq/

Comment: Thanks, what is the performance like with Moq? RhinoMocks has a similar syntax, but is much slower than real classes (as long as they're in-memory only). I would like to avoid the rather complex syntax of `.Setup(...)` or `.Stub()` in RhinoMocks. I expect the framework to create a new type at runtime, which is instantiated like a regular class, doing reflection only once and then having performance like a coded class.